# my iOS game app is not working on Devices

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, gameplay-kit

I create a small iOS game app using SpriteKit in Xcode. It's working properly on simulators but in devices it doesn't create  nodes. In code I set to create  nodes dynamically, it is working
On Simulator but not working On devices

**On Simulator**
[image]

**On Devices**
[image]

```
@objc func createRoadStrip(){
    let leftRoadStrip = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 60))
    leftRoadStrip.strokeColor = .white
    leftRoadStrip.fillColor = .white
    leftRoadStrip.position.x = -187
    leftRoadStrip.position.y =  700
    leftRoadStrip.zPosition = 10
    leftRoadStrip.alpha = 0.4
    leftRoadStrip.name = "leftRoadStrip"
    addChild(leftRoadStrip)

    let rightRoadStrip = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 60))
    rightRoadStrip.strokeColor = .white
    rightRoadStrip.fillColor = .white
    rightRoadStrip.position.x = 187
    rightRoadStrip.position.y =  700
    rightRoadStrip.zPosition = 10
    rightRoadStrip.alpha = 0.4
    rightRoadStrip.name = "rightRoadStrip"

    addChild(rightRoadStrip)

}



func moveRoadStrip(){
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "leftRoadStrip") { (strip, stop) in
        let leftRoadStrip = strip as! SKShapeNode
        leftRoadStrip.position.y -= 40
    }

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "rightRoadStrip") { (strip, stop) in
        let rightRoadStrip = strip as! SKShapeNode
        rightRoadStrip.position.y -= 40
    }

}

 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
   //here
    moveRoadStrip()
    moveTrafficCar()
    if(carCanMove){
        moveCar(toLeftSide: leftCarToMoveLeft)
        moveCar(toRightSide: rightCarToMoveRight)
    }
    removeItems()
}
```

I call the Timer (create road strip ) in didMove method and move the road strip  in update function

```
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    setUp()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(createRoadStrip), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
   //here
    moveRoadStrip()
}
```

My device version is

- iOS: 9.0, model iPhone 6

Comment: @aBilal17 Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: show us more details. as your  update(_ currentTime:) clearly shows that your nodes are increasing, so your app will eventually crash. you don't specify how your Timer used and where?

Comment: I think the Problem is on iOS version not on device.                                 I tried in iOS 9.0 simulator it  cause the same error  which I faced in the device

Comment: `update(_:)` method calls each engine loop frame (60 times per second)... your strips just fly off the screen faster than you have time to notice them...

Comment: But this happens only in ios 9 .0 is there any thing depend upon the version

Comment: anyone know the correct reason for this ?